How can I free space from my computer? df -h shows the 217 GB being used, but I don't know how to free it
I am trying to free up a lot of space on my computer, but am unable to find where exactly most of my space is taken up. The storage statistics on my computer tell me that Ubuntu is using 115 GB of space and I can't figure out how to free it. I am using Ubuntu 18.04.5 on Windows 11. I have included the output from df -h:
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb        251G   22G  217G  10% /
none            1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /mnt/wsl
tools           225G  217G  8.4G  97% /init
none            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
none            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /run
none            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /run/lock
none            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /run/shm
none            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /run/user
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
drivers         225G  217G  8.4G  97% /usr/lib/wsl/drivers
lib             225G  217G  8.4G  97% /usr/lib/wsl/lib
drvfs           225G  217G  8.4G  97% /mnt/c

I am not sure about how to access the file systems listed that take up 217 GB and what is safe to delete. Apologies for the novice question, I am not an expert user.
Thank you!

18,04 has gone end of life a long time ago so is off topic here. Do plan an install for a newer version (24.04 is almost here ;) but ... do install baobab if it is  not already, it will let you drilldown into directories using a graph

You may find this helpful: No more disk space: How can I find what is taking up the space?

Your Linux root filesystem is only 10% full, at 22GB.  The wsl files are really part of Windows support for the subsystem for Linux.
